# Get all night time dates in Java

Tags: java, date, arraylist

I've been trying to sort a list of Crimes and sort the objects into daytime and nightime lists. So daytime can be between 6am to 10pm and night time can be between 10pm and 6am.
I've wrote an if statement to try and populate a list of night crimes.

```
    if(data.getDate().getHours() < 6 && data.getDate().getHours() > 22) {
            System.out.println(data.getDate().toLocaleString());
            nightCrimes.add(data);
    }
```

Although nothing prints out and the list remains empty. I've noticed that the logic is clearly wrong because a particular integer (Hour) cannot be more than 22 and less than 6. Is there any better way for me to go about this?

Comment: Seems that your problem is that you're using `&&` instead of `||`. You want `or`, not `and`

Comment: Cheers leave answer and I'll upvote

Comment: The real answer here is to pick a book and **learn** what the code you are writing means. As in: "&&" is an operator. There are others in Java. Research what they are, and what they do for you.

Comment: If you cannot avoid getting an old-fashioned `Date` object from you data, you can and should at least avoid using its deprecated `getHours` and `toLocaleString` methods. The `Date` class has design problems and is long outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you need to change is replace && with ||.
Here is the new if statement

```
if(data.getDate().getHours() < 6 || data.getDate().getHours() > 22)
```

Comment: Actually, that should be `….getHours() >= 22` (greater-than-or-equals 22, not greater-than 22) according to the prose of the Question: *night time can be between 10pm and 6am*.

Comment: … and you still shouldn’t use the deprecated `getHours` method (and not `Date` at all if you can avoid it). But I’m repeating myself.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

As the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53686054/642706) by George Fox says, the direct answer to your question is using logical OR rather than AND.

But you have other problems with your code:

- Ignoring crucial issue of **time zone**
- Using bloody **awful date-time classes**, now obsolete.

Code snippet:

```
data
.getDate()                         // Using terrible old `java.time.Date` class.
.toInstant()                       // Convert from legacy class to modern class.
.atZone(                           // Adjust from UTC to your own local time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )    // Use proper time zone name in `Continent/Region` format.
)                                  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object, a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
.getHour()                         // Returns an `int` for hour-of-day.
```

… ( is equal to or greater than 22 ) OR ( is less than 6 ) = a nighttime value.

## java.time

Apparently you are using the terrible old date-time classes, deducing that your call to `getHours` is [`java.util.Date::getHours`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours()).

Those legacy classes were supplanted years ago by the industry-leading *java.time* classes.

By the way, `Date::getHours` is deprecated as well.

## Time zone

If you are using `java.util.Date`, then you are ignoring the crucial issue of time zone. A `Date` represents a moment in UTC, always UTC by definition.

So, unless you live in Iceland, asking for the hour of the day in UTC is *not* going to match your own local day and night times.

First convert your `Date` to a modern [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). For that you can use the new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;  // Convert from legacy class to modern class.
```

Then apply a time zone for your locality, to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Compare the hour-of-day as seen in your Question.

```
static final int MORNING_HOUR = 6 ;
static final int EVENING_HOUR = 22 ;
…
int hour = zdt.getHour() ;
boolean isNighttime = 
    ( hour >= EVENING_HOUR )  // Include this hour.
    || 
    ( hour < MORNING_HOUR )   // Exclude this hour.
;
```

You might collect those into a `Map` where the key is a string “nighttime” or “daytime” and value is a `Set` of `Crime` objects. A `Set` eliminates duplicates. If you want the crimes to be sorted use a `SortedSet`.

```
Map < String, SortedSet < Crime > > dayOrNight = new HashMap <>( 2 );
dayOrNight.put( "daytime" , new TreeSet <>() );
dayOrNight.put( "nighttime" , new TreeSet <>() );
```

Collect.

```
if( isNighttime ) { 
    dayOrNight.get( "nighttime" ).add( crime ) ;
} else {  // Else, must be daytime.
    dayOrNight.get( "daytime" ).add( crime ) ;
}
```

Let's next spin that code to use a time-on-day rather than hour-of-day in case your business rules are ever redefined to be a partial hour.

Spans-of-time are usually best defined using the Half-Open approach. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So night time begins with first moment of the 10 PM hour and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of 6 AM.

Tip: A shorter way of asking “if equal to or later than 10 PM” is “If not before

```
LocalTime morning = LocalTime.of( 6 , 0 ) ;
LocalTime evening = LocalTime.of( 22 , 0 ) ;

LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
boolean isNighttime = ( ! lt.isBefore( evening ) ) || lt.isBefore( morning ) ;

if( isNighttime ) { 
    dayOrNight.get( "nighttime" ).add( crime ) ;
} else {  // Else, must be daytime.
    dayOrNight.get( "daytime" ).add( crime ) ;
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).